# Unable to send MultiPart file from flutter app to AWS lambda

Tags: flutter, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I've created a mobile app in which there are forms and images, I've setup a lambda function and API gateway for uploading these images to s3 bucket, when I send the images through postman, it works fine and I get the URLs of the Uploaded Images, but when I'm trying to send them from my flutter app I'm getting this error

> "I/flutter (16967): Upload failed with status code: 500>I/flutter (16967): Error message: {"message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')"}"

In my postman If I don't select the "files" checkbox and don't select a file, it gives the same error.

> |||"image_uploader.dart"|||
>
> import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
> import 'package:path/path.dart'; // Import for basename function
> import 'package:mime/mime.dart'; // Import for lookupMimeType function
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
> import 'package:myapp23/formModel.dart';
> import 'package:myapp23/formData.dart';
> import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
>
> ```
> Future<void> uploadImages(BuildContext context) async {
> try {
> FormModel formModel = Provider.of<FormModel>(context, listen: false);
> FormData formData;
>
> if (formModel.selectedFormIndex != -1) {
> formData = formModel.forms[formModel.selectedFormIndex];`
> else {
> formModel.createForm();
> formData = formModel.forms[formModel.selectedFormIndex];
>       }`
>
> List<String> singleFilePaths = formData.singleImageFiles.map((file) => file.path).toList();`
> var url = Uri.parse('https://abcdefghi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/file/upload');`
>
> var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
> request.headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
> `
> if (singleFilePaths.isNotEmpty) {
> for (var file in singleFilePaths) {`
> if (file != null) {
> var mimeType = lookupMimeType(file);
> if (mimeType != null) {``
> var mimeTypeSplit = mimeType.split('/');
> var singleFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(`
>                 'singlefile',
> file,
> contentType: MediaType.parse(lookupMimeType(file) ?? ''),
> filename: basename(file),`
>               );
> request.files.add(singleFile);
> break; // Adding only the first valid file from the single files list
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }`
>
> var streamedResponse = await request.send();
> if (streamedResponse.statusCode == 200) {
> var response = await streamedResponse.stream.bytesToString();
> print('Response received: $response');
> Handle the response as needed...
> else {
> print('Upload failed withh4 status code: ${streamedResponse.statusCode}');
> print('Error message: ${await streamedResponse.stream.bytesToString()}');
>       }
> catch (e) {
> print('Error uploading image: $e');
>     }
>   }
> }`
>
> |||"index.js"|||
>
> `const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
> const parseMultipart = require('parse-multipart');
>
> const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET;
>
> `const s3 = new AWS.S3();
> `
> module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
> try {
> const files = extractFiles(event);
>
> if (!files || files.length === 0) {
> throw new Error('No files uploaded');
>     }
>
>    ` `const uploadPromises = files.map(async ({ filename, data }) => {`
> if (!filename || !data || data.length === 0) {
> return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid file data'));
>       }``
>
> await s3.putObject({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: 'folder1/' + filename, ACL: 'public-read', Body: data }).promise();
> return `https://${BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${filename}`;
>     });
> ```

`>

> `const uploadResults = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);`
> return {
> statusCode: 200,
> `> body: JSON.stringify({ links: uploadResults }) };`
> catch (err) {
> return {
> 'statusCode: 500,
> `body: JSON.stringify({ message: err.message })`
> }; `` }` }; ``
> `function extractFiles(event) {`const boundary = parseMultipart.getBoundary(event.headers['content-type']); `const files = parseMultipart.Parse(Buffer.f`your text`rom(event.body, 'base64'), boundary);`
> return files.map(({ filename, data }) => ({ filename, data }));
> }

Comment: Your code is a huge mess. Please delete that section of the question and add your code back -- and either indent it with 4 spaces, or add 3 backticks \` around it